# Grabbing data from Many-to-Many middle table using through active record

Tags: php, activerecord, many-to-many, yii

I have exactly the same question posted here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/25763-grab-data-from-many-to-many-middle-table-using-through/

What and how can the **through** option help us in a Many-to-Many relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'through' creates a relation between two tables that are not linked by foreign keys, but by a middle table. For instance, let's imagine I have 3 models: Groups, Users, and Comments. The relations would be like this:

Groups---(hasMany)--->Users----(hasMany)----->Comments.

Groups and Comments are not linked by a foreign key, but using 'trough' they will act as if they were. This of course means that we can enjoy all the benefits of AR in relational queries. For example, you could get all the comments of the users who belong to a certain group simply by:

```
$group->comments;
```

Here you can find a more detailed (but perhaps a bit more technical) explanation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Just as an advice, I strongly recommend to use eager loading here. It's a bit large to explain why, but if you use it, you'll avoid AR to perform a exponential number of join queries.